# Find values on specific positions in string

Tags: php, math

How can I find a value on a specific place in a string with PHP?

Like with the string "1+3=4":

1. Put the characters before the '+', '*', '/' or '-' in a variable
2. Put the plus in a variable. It may be '+', '*', '/' or '-'
3. Put the characters after the '+', '*', '/' or '-' in a variable
4. Put the character after the '=' in a variable

Like with the string "7*9=63":

```
$first = "7";
$mathSymbol = "*";
$second = "9";
$answer = "63";
```

And with "15+120=135":

```
$first = "15";
$mathSymbol = "+";
$second = "120";
$answer = "135";
```

Comment: How about `preg_match` and [a regular expression](http://regex101.com/r/cX8nG9)?

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "7+9=16";
for($i = 0; $i < (strlen($str)); $i++){
   if($str[$i] != '='){
    $str.$i = $str[$i];
    //echo $str[$i];//To see what it contains
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can try with this.this might help u
[link](http://www.phpdevtips.com/2011/07/exploding-a-string-using-multiple-delimiters-using-php/)